# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Navigation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**- question 1:::::
*Obstacle detection or navigation exists in ROS; can I implement my own
navigation algorithm. Whether it will
create problem with existing
navigation algorithms? Or am I
allowed to change any code in ROS.*
Suppose I want to generate a behavior
which will guide me to perform an
action. Will there be problem if any
behavior generation scheme already
exists in any of the controllers.**

**question 2::: If I go for both autonomy and teleop; will it be a
problem for ROS?**

Consider a situation like earthquake comes and person in the wheelchair fainted; then wheelchair automatically detects the movement of the objects by motion sensor and afterwards it has to find the door. In general he/she will control the wheelchair in teleop mode.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76837/ros-navigation/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can replace any part of the navigation stack that you want. Mostly it's plugins, which you can create from scratch or build on the provided ones.

For autonomy and teleop you only need to make sure that both don't interfere, i.e. somewhere you need to decide, which commands get priority.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a simple mux for allowing both navigation and teleop commands to control a robot, it's a pretty simple process, here's an example for you to get your feet wet:

[https://github.com/dawonn/ros-pioneer3at/blob/master/scripts/mux_cmdvel]

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-08**:
There is also cmd_vel_mux http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux, used in the turtlebot config.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-08**:
That is a much better solution than my silly script! I'm probably going to convert my robot to that. :) Thanks.